# Importing CSV data to Google sheets using Appscript giving parse error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have csv file uploaded to drive daily through google forms. I need process the data in the file to decide on some actions but am running into a parse error for the file

The csv file link is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6tuNEqpOxle3J99g0NL88GvDCNZoOM0/view?usp=sharing

The google sheet I am using is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11UegtqQLrY3iQMek6LLNofOHjMzo9HhndYgOU4UQhrA/edit?usp=sharing

Script is given below

```js
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1e6tuNEqpOxle3J99g0NL88GvDCNZoOM0");
  Logger.log(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

It gives the error below

> Exception: Could not parse text.
> importCSVFromGoogleDrive  @ Code.gs:5

As I can see the logger it getting data but I am not sure how to locate the reason for the error. Also if there is simpler way to do this it would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your csv contains break lines inside cells:

[image]

You need to replace these breaks with something (spaces, for example) before you parse the csv.

Something like this:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1e6tuNEqpOxle3J99g0NL88GvDCNZoOM0");
  var string = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

  for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
    string = string.replace( /(\"[^\n\"]+)\n([^\"]+\")/g, "$1 $2" );

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(string,",");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

### Update

Here is a more clean solution to replace all `\n` with spaces inside quote marks:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1e6tuNEqpOxle3J99g0NL88GvDCNZoOM0");
  var string = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

  string.match(/"[^"]+"/g).forEach(t => 
    string = string.split(t).join(t.replace(/\n/g,' ')));
  
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(string,",");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Unlike the previous quick dirty solution this code will replace not only five of `\n`s inside quote marks but all of them.

It looks quite tricky and it took me a couple hours to figure out how it can be done without the four loops, conditions, counters, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the pointer. While this worked I wanted to understand why the for loop is needed and specifically to run 5 times

Comment: The loop is a rather quick dirty solution. It just repeats the replacing five times. Because the data contains up to four of five line breaks in some cells. For more line breaks you will need more iterations. Actually there should be a more smart solution. Say, you can search for "..\n..." and do replace while there are not empty search results. Or, perhaps, there is some RegExp that able to replace all line breaks inside quotes in one step, I don't know.

Comment: Works. Would update if any further bugs encountered. Thanks for the quick input and solution